# React native Activity Indicator only works when device is connected to laptop

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Activity indicator works as expected when my device is plugged to my laptop during development and debugging.

but as soon as I unplug it and run the app, activity indicator doesn't display at all, even in a release build.

I have no idea what's going on.

```
render() {
 return (
  <View style={Styles.container}>
    {this.state.status === LOADING ? (
      <ActivityIndicator
        style={{ marginTop: 24 }}
        color={Variables.primaryColor}
        size={80}
        animating={true}
      />
    ) : null}

    {this.state.status === GET_NETWORK_FEED_SUCCESS ? (
      <FeedList posts={this.state.feed} />
    ) : null}

    {this.state.status === SERVER_ERROR ? (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 24, alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Icon name="sad" style={Styles.Text_large} />
        <Text>OOps, there was an error getting your feed.</Text>
      </View>
    ) : null}
  </View>
);
```

}